# Mage-messages cookie messages not displayed in magento 2.4.2

Tags: magento2, cookie, magento2.4.2, messages

I am facing an issue that Magento pages like customer registration, login, forgot password, etc not showing any success or error message.

I found that cookie with the name mage-messages generated twice, one is having a message but the other is blank.

I have 1 website , 1 store view , 1 store
[image]

Comment: DId you get solution for this?

Comment: @sreedarsh, check this https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/32220

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

> ***Method-1 Using Module***

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend**

**requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Theme/js/view/messages':'VendoreName_ModuleName/js/view/messages'
        }
    }
};
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/js/view**

**messages.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'underscore',
    'escaper',
    'jquery/jquery-storageapi'
], function ($, Component, customerData, _, escaper) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            cookieMessages: [],
            messages: [],
            allowedTags: ['div', 'span', 'b', 'strong', 'i', 'em', 'u', 'a']
        },

        /**
         * Extends Component object by storage observable messages.
         */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();

            this.cookieMessages = _.unique($.cookieStorage.get('mage-messages'), 'text');
            this.messages = customerData.get('messages').extend({
                disposableCustomerData: 'messages'
            });

            // Force to clean obsolete messages
            if (!_.isEmpty(this.messages().messages)) {
                customerData.set('messages', {});
            }

            $.cookieStorage.setConf({path: '/', expires: -1}).set('mage-messages', null);

        },

        /**
         * Prepare the given message to be rendered as HTML
         *
         * @param {String} message
         * @return {String}
         */
        prepareMessageForHtml: function (message) {
            return escaper.escapeHtml(message, this.allowedTags);
        }
    });
});
```

> ***Method-2 Using Theme***

**app/design/frontend/your-vendor-name/your-theme-name/Magento_Theme/web/js/view**

**messages.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'underscore',
    'escaper',
    'jquery/jquery-storageapi'
], function ($, Component, customerData, _, escaper) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            cookieMessages: [],
            messages: [],
            allowedTags: ['div', 'span', 'b', 'strong', 'i', 'em', 'u', 'a']
        },

        /**
         * Extends Component object by storage observable messages.
         */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();

            this.cookieMessages = _.unique($.cookieStorage.get('mage-messages'), 'text');
            this.messages = customerData.get('messages').extend({
                disposableCustomerData: 'messages'
            });

            // Force to clean obsolete messages
            if (!_.isEmpty(this.messages().messages)) {
                customerData.set('messages', {});
            }

            $.cookieStorage.setConf({path: '/', expires: -1}).set('mage-messages', null);

        },

        /**
         * Prepare the given message to be rendered as HTML
         *
         * @param {String} message
         * @return {String}
         */
        prepareMessageForHtml: function (message) {
            return escaper.escapeHtml(message, this.allowedTags);
        }
    });
});
```

**Must be run Magento 2 commands after adding the above files**

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento s:d:c
php bin/magento c:c
```

Comment: can you explain your fix sir ?